# Add a custom namespace to visual studio generated service references

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a project in VS (say MyProject) and I am using a namespace that doesn't start with the name of the project itself. For Example: for a class 'MyClass', I am using namespace that looks something like this MyCompany.MyFeature.MyProject.Models. Now I added a Service reference to the project and Visual studio generated code for me. However, for the classes generated by VS it always use namespace starting with 'MyProject'.

Now, I want to change the default namespace provided by the VS (i.e. MyProject) to my namespace (i.e. MyCompany.MyFeature.MyProject).

I tried this : http://www.thorarin.net/blog/post/2010/05/31/Customizing-Visual-Studio-generated-service-reference-namespaces.aspx but it didn't work.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: A couple of regions:
First of all to follow the standard used for namespace by the entire team..
Secondly, if you have a namespace say 'xyz'  and a class under it. And you want to refer it in a class which is under namespace abc.xyz (not the same namespace as the first xyz), it is not possible. So, in above example I cannot refer the class generated by the VS because if I try to refer namespace 'MyProject' the compiler always refers to 'MyCompany.MyFeature.MyProject'.

Comment: It is fairly unclear why you dislike you project name so much.  Project + Properties, Application tab, Root namespace property.

Comment: @HansPassant: Your solution worked. Thanks a lot for your help. I really appreciate that. :)
Also, I don't dislike the project name, its just because that is how it was done before I joined the team.